# Extending the metric of a hyperbolic surface with boundary to its double

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $M$ be a hyperbolic surface with totally geodesic boundary. Taking the double $DM$ of $M$, it is easy to see using Euler characteristic that $DM$ is itself a hyperbolic surface (without boundary). We can obtain a Riemannian metric of constant sectional curvature $-1$ on $DM$ by extending the metric on $M$ in the obvious way. Is this metric smooth? Of course it's smooth except possibly on the boundary of $M$ - the question is whether the metric is smooth there.

This seems to be a fact which is assumed in a lot of sources I've consulted. However, from reading other posts on Stackexchange (this one for instance: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140386/regularity-of-metric-of-the-double-of-a-riemannian-manifold), I've gathered that a metric obtained in this way is not smooth in general for the double of an arbitrary Riemannian manifold.

Comment: The metric is smooth because the universal cover IS the upper half space, and all geodesic in the upper half space is identified with (eg.) the imaginary axis. Then the double of M will be locally the same as a neighborhood of that geodesic, thus the metric is smooth.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of a hyperbolic surface with totally geodesic boundary is locally modelled on the left half of the upper half-space model
$$\{(x,y) \bigm| x \le 0, y>0\}
$$
with the usual upper half-space metric $(dx^2 + dy^2)/y^2$. So it suffices to notice that the double of the left half of upper half space is all of upper half space, on which the metric is certainly smooth.